# Prove if a set is Zariski closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to show if a set is Zariski closed?

There are two sets:

$1. \ \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \subset \mathbb{A}^1$,

$2. \ \{(s^2,st,t^2) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : s, t \in \mathbb{C} \} \subset \mathbb{A}^3$.

My idea was:

In the Zariski topology a set is closed if it is algebraic, so one has to find a polynomial with roots in the set.

For the first I got:

A polynomial with roots from $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is $x-x_1, ..., x-x_n$ with $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, so $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \subset \mathbb{A}^1$ is Zariski closed.

Is this correct or how to prove if this set is Zariski closed or not?

For $2.$ I don't know how to show it. My idea was to write $(s^2,st,t^2)$ in terms of the others but I don't get the right result.

Comment: No, you need to find polynomials *vanishing on the whole set*. Try again.

Comment: Rethink about the first set.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the first set, you need a polynomial that vanishes on $\mathbf C\setminus \{0\}$, but not on $\{0\}$. Is this possible?
2. For the second part, note that $(st)^2 - s^2t^2 = 0$. Does this help?